# Get difference in months between two datepickers

Tags: delphi, datetime, calendar

I have this code I use to get the difference between two datepickers in Delphi.

```
procedure TForm.CreateForm;
var
currDate : TDateTime;
begin
  currDate := Now;
  dtpStartDate.Date := currDate;
  dtpEndDate.Date :=  IncMonth(currDate);

end;

procedure TForm.updateLabelandBtn;
var
monthsDiff :Double;
begin
monthsDiff := (MonthOf( dtpEndDate.Date ) - MonthOf( dtpStartDate.Date )) + ((DayOf( dtpEndDate.Date ) - DayOf( dtpStartDate.Date))/32);
if (dtpEndDate.Date > dtpStartDate.Date ) then
 begin
  if (monthsDiff >1 ) then
   begin
    lblMsg.Caption := 'Wait';
    btnStart.Enabled := True;
   end
 end
else
 begin
  btnStart.Enabled := False;
  lblMsg.Caption := 'start date should be smaller than end date.';
 end;
end;

procedure TForm.dtpEndDateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
updateLabelandBtn;
end;


procedure TForm.dtpStartDateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
updateLabelandBtn;

end;
end.
```

When I run the program and the form pops up with two datepickers by default I set the date with a month difference.

If I try to change the end date, in the first change it works fine, but then if i try to change it again it won't update the label according to the difference in months between start date and end date.
Basically the onchange event doesn't capture all events, or at least that's what I understand. I need to get the output of the updateLabelandBtn procedure correctly.

This is a subform called from another form like this:

```
 begin
    try
      Form.CreateForm;
      if Form.ShowModal = mrOk then
      RunQuery;
    finally
      Form.Release
    end
```

Input example:

```
Start date 10.01.2017
End Date 12.02.2017
Label becomes wait 
button is enabled

Start date 10.01.2017
End Date 08.01.2017
Label becomes start date should be bigger than end date 
button is disabled
```

Comment: Try MonthsBetween() function

Comment: @GorAsatryan I tried that, but I''m not sure is the function itself the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that all "begin-end"-s are correct? I expected to see "begin" after `if (monthsDiff >1 )`

Comment: @GorAsatryan exactly, that's what I am sating, it should be something with the syntax..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not consistent". You should provide some example inputs, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's strange because the button gets enabled and siabled according to the conditions, but the label itself doesn't update.

Comment: Try debugging. And how about providing what I requested?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think I am clear with the output, when I say that  I want to check first whether the end date is bigger than the start date, if yes, i want to check if the difference in months is bigger than 1 and display a message and if end date is not bigger that start date I want to display another message.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan when i try to change the date for the first time then it responds to the if conditions, but if i keep changing then it stops responding

Comment: You will likely get a better reception if you ask clearer questions.

Comment: If the function stops responding then the problem is not likely to be in the code that you show. You need to give us a complete sample program that demonstrates your issue - and - just as important - explain what goes wrong. People on this site give their time free of charge and you need to help us to help you.

Comment: You should provide some example inputs, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan done!

Comment: So now do some debugging to see why that happens. Look at intermediate values.

Comment: You are aware that you only set the label under a few of the possible conditions? If you enter any of the other possible conditions nothing changes. To start with try following the rule that for every **if** there should be an **else** to cope with the opposite possibility. I think that then you will see your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your diff calculation is rather strange, so I suggest instead to use `DaysBetween()` and `DaysInMonth()` functions:

```
if DaysBetween(dtpEndDate.Date, dtpStartDate.Date) >= DaysInMonth(dtpStartDate.Date) then
```

(see edit below)

This accepts correctly e.g. Feb 1 and March 1 as well as July 1 and August 1 or Dec 15 Jan 15 (next year)

Secondly, I understand that there must be a minimum time of 1 month from start to end. You should add an error message when this condition is not fulfilled.

---

Edit after "saastn" commented on this answer in their own answer, and pointed out the error when start date is on a day that doesn't exist in the following month and the end date is on the first or second of subsequent month. E.g start date = 31.1 and end date = 1.3. To cover these dates, they suggested to also consider the difference in month ordinals, and thus the formula becomes

```
if ((DaysBetween(dtpEndDate.Date, dtpStartDate.Date) >= DaysInMonth(dtpStartDate.Date)) or
    (MonthOf(dtpEndDate.Date) - MonthOf(dtpStartDate.Date) >= 2)) then
```

Please, read further in the answer by "saastn"

Comment: Thank you, this was quite e nice solution. With some modifications to my initial code I made it work! Thank you!

Comment: There are exceptions that your answer does not handle, please read my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the accepted answer, seems like this question has narrowed down to *"How to check if difference between two dates is less than a month?"*. Toms suggests using `DaysBetween` and `DaysInMonth` functions. The following function uses his logic:

```
function DatesDiffLessThanAMonth_Tom(const FromDate, ToDate: TDate): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    (DaysBetween(ToDate, FromDate) <= DaysInMonth(FromDate));
end;
```

It works in most cases but there still are some exceptions:

```
FromDate     ToDate        DsIM1   DsB
2016-01-30 - 2016-03-01    31      31
2016-01-31 - 2016-03-01    31      30
2016-01-31 - 2016-03-02    31      31
2016-03-31 - 2016-05-01    31      31
2016-05-31 - 2016-07-01    31      31
2016-08-31 - 2016-10-01    31      31
2016-10-31 - 2016-12-01    31      31
2017-01-29 - 2017-03-01    31      31
2017-01-30 - 2017-03-01    31      30
2017-01-30 - 2017-03-02    31      31
2017-01-31 - 2017-03-01    31      29
2017-01-31 - 2017-03-02    31      30
2017-01-31 - 2017-03-03    31      31
2017-03-31 - 2017-05-01    31      31
2017-05-31 - 2017-07-01    31      31
2017-08-31 - 2017-10-01    31      31
2017-10-31 - 2017-12-01    31      31
```

We can take month of the date into account to overcome this problem:

```
function DatesDiffLessThanAMonth_Tom_Mod(const FromDate, ToDate: TDate): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    (DaysBetween(ToDate, FromDate) <= DaysInMonth(FromDate)) and
    (MonthOf(ToDate) - MonthOf(FromDate) < 2);
end;
```

I checked this with another function which I believe is more readable and is slightly faster(2938 ms compared to 4125 ms for 18221216 calls), and they both returned same results for dates from 1900 to 5000:

```
function DatesDiffLessThanAMonth(const FromDate, ToDate: TDate): Boolean;
var
  Y1, M1, D1, Y2, M2, D2: Word;
begin
  DecodeDate(FromDate, Y1, M1, D1);
  DecodeDate(ToDate, Y2, M2, D2);
  Result :=
    ((Y1 = Y2) and (M1 = M2)) or
    ((Y1 = Y2) and (M1 = M2 -1) and (D2 <= D1)) or
    ((Y1 = Y2 - 1) and (M1 = 12) and (M2 = 1) and (D2<=D1));
end;
```

The other advantage of this function is that it can be used for other 12-monthed calendar systems like [Solar Hijri (Jalali)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar) and [Islamic (the Lunar one)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) calendars. In fact I developed this function for Hijri calendar basically. I am not aware of any reliable date libraries for this calendar that contain `DaysBetween` and `DaysInMonth` functions, while there are [well tested libraries](http://forum.arneweb.ir/%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE-%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%81%DB%8C/) for encoding and decoding dates in Hijri and converting them to/from Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Thank you for notifying, I edited my answer accordingly. Your answer is a good one, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a 'begin' between 'then' and 'lblMsg.Caption := 'Wait'. It's easy to see the problem when your code is formatted.

```
if (dtpEndDate.Date > dtpStartDate.Date ) then
 begin
  if (monthsDiff >1 )
   then lblMsg.Caption := 'Wait';  // oops!
  btnStart.Enabled := True;
 end
```

It should be

```
if (dtpEndDate.Date > dtpStartDate.Date ) then
 begin
  if (monthsDiff >1 ) then
   begin
    lblMsg.Caption := 'Wait';  
    btnStart.Enabled := True;
   end
 end
else
 begin
  btnStart.Enabled := False;
  lblMsg.Caption := 'start date should be smaller than end date.';
 end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, it still doesn't do the job, it seems like it has something to do with the monthsDiff variable..

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic problem using either MonthSpan or MonthsBetween in that both give an approximation based on the average length of a month (30.4375 days per month). I suspect you want something more like the following:

### Edited to take years into account:

```
function LogicalMonthSpan( const pDate1, pDate2 : TDateTime ) : Double;
begin
  Result := (YearOf( pDate2 ) - YearOf(pDate1))* 12 + (MonthOf( pDate2 ) - MonthOf( pDate1 )) + ((DayOf( PDate2 ) - DayOf( pDate1))/32);
end;
```

which would consider 15 Feb to 16th March to be > 1 month, whereas MonthSpan would show it it be less than 1 month

Comment: This really helped me, but this will display the correct result only for dates of the same year, because for dates with different years it doesn't work properly. Could you help me out with also taking the year into account?

Comment: See update for taking years into account. I should have thought of that!